# reactjs offline application rest api's not loading while enable service-worker

Tags: reactjs, offline-caching, offlineapps

I have build reactjs offline application. I am using serviceworker to load data offline mode, But it is not working. For data loading i am using back-end rest api's. In offline mode api's are not loading.
PFA,
[rest api's network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fFzu.png)

I have registered serviceworker by using default serviceworker provided by reactjs. In index.js by using serviceWorker.register() method.
I have build and deploy my application by using thsese commands npm run build and serve -s build